# Code-compliant way of permanently wiring a hidden 120v appliance

Tags: electrical, receptacle, junction-box, splices

I'm finishing my basement and want to install an inline booster fan for one of the bedrooms. The fan will be accessible by removing a rain shower head in the bathroom, since the duct runs right above it. So it's not super easy to get to, but if it burns out in a couple years I can still replace it.

What's a code-compliant way of wiring up the fan? It comes with a regular 2-prong receptacle plug. I'm ok with either installing a receptacle in there (if I can) or cutting the plug off and splicing it directly to NM cable (romex).

My understanding is that a receptacle must be "easily accessible", which I don't think this qualifies as. In terms of splices, I'm reading conflicting information about whether they must be inside a junction box and whether that box must also be accessible.

I'm in Canada, as far as I know we pretty much follow NEC.

Comment: Receptacle is in a box which must be accessible. Junction box by itself (i.e., just for hardwiring) must be accessible. Most splices (there are certain ones designed and allowed to be hidden) must be accessible. And you can't (except arguably for temporary use/testing) chop off a plug and splice direct to Romex - and if you *could*, the splice would need to be accessible.

Comment: Instead of a booster fan, would you consider replacing the duct with one of larger size and/or fewer elbows? Such changes could eliminate the need for the booster.

Comment: You need an access panel for the fan and/or the cable connections.  Can you do that above the shower?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact so there's no way to do this without an access panel?

Comment: @GregHill Already tried. It's as straight of a run as possible and it's upsized from 5'' to 6'' in the basement run from the main plenum up to where it enters the wall. The room is still not as warm as the rest. Fed a camera through the duct, found nothing.

Comment: @Egor As far as I know, removing parts of equipment to access that equipment's junction box is perfectly fine (and normal) - e.g., to get to the junction box above a bathroom exhaust fan or above a light fixture. But to have remove equipment "a" (shower head) to get to equipment "b" (booster fan) doesn't work.

Comment: UL approved the instructions as part of approving the equipment. NEC 110.3 requries you follow them.  What do they say about installation of the fan?